# How can I get output values into output parameters?

Tags: c#, postgresql, parameters

I am using C# in VS 2008 to retrieve data from a PostgreSQL stored procedure that has two input parameters and two output parameters.  When I created the procedure, PostgreSQL told me that I had to specify that it returns a record.

In VS2008, my first attempt to use the procedure involved creating an `OdbcCommand` object of type `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and giving it four parameters, two with direction of Input and two of direction Output.  The command executed without error, first using `ExecuteNonQuery()` and then using `ExecuteReader()`, but the values of the output parameters were null.  I called the reader's `GetValues()` function, and found that the result was a single object containing the string `"{3,4}"`.

Then, following a suggestion from StackOverflow, I changed the command text to:
    {call closest_idle_cover(?, ?, ?, ?)}

This also worked, and `GetValues()` gave me an array of two objects of type int, one with 3 and the other with 4.  This was quite a bit better, since I wouldn't have to parse a string.  But the output parameters still have null values, and indeed, the command works just as well if I only pass in the two input parameters.

So, although I have a solution that works, I remain curious:  How can I get the values into my output parameters?

Here's the PostgreSQL stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION plant_genie.closest_idle_cover(IN int, IN int, OUT int, OUT int)
  RETURNS record AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    current_x ALIAS FOR $1;
    current_y ALIAS FOR $2;
    target_x ALIAS FOR $3;
    target_y ALIAS FOR $4;
    coverLocations ic_storage_locations%rowtype;
BEGIN
    target_x := 3;
    target_y := 4;  

    SELECT INTO coverLocations * 
    FROM ic_storage_locations 
    WHERE inner_cover IS NOT NULL 
    ORDER BY sqrt(pow(current_x - ic_storage_locations.x_coordinate, 2) + 
            pow(current_y - ic_storage_locations.y_coordinate, 2))
    LIMIT 1;

    IF FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO op_messages (message) VALUES ('Found a cover location record.');
        target_x := coverLocations.x_coordinate;
        target_y := coverLocations.y_coordinate;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO op_messages (message) VALUES ('Could not find a cover location record.');
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE COST 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `OUT` parameters but then also a `RETURNS record` clause, without having an explicit `RETURN` statement in the body of the function. That combination does not work. A more elegant solution than using `OUT` parameters is to define the output table format - it is more obvious what is going on:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION plant_genie.closest_idle_cover(current_x int, current_y int)
RETURNS TABLE (target_x int, target_y int) AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    coverLocations ic_storage_locations%rowtype;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO coverLocations * 
    FROM ic_storage_locations 
    WHERE inner_cover IS NOT NULL 
    ORDER BY pow(current_x - ic_storage_locations.x_coordinate, 2) + 
             pow(current_y - ic_storage_locations.y_coordinate, 2)
    LIMIT 1;

    IF FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO op_messages (message) VALUES ('Found a cover location record.');
        RETURN QUERY SELECT coverLocations.x_coordinate, coverLocations.y_coordinate;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO op_messages (message) VALUES ('Could not find a cover location record.');
    END IF;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' STRICT;
```

So if you call this function you are returned a record if at least 1 ic_storage_location is not null:

```
SELECT * FROM plant_genie.closest_idle_cover(1, 2);
```

You can deal with that in your C# code like you would any other data you pull out of the database.

A few observations:

- Since you are looking for the nearest ic_storage_location you can dispense with the `SQRT()` function call, which is computationally expensive. Just working with the squared sums has the same property of ordering records by distance from the current location.
- The function is defined as `STRICT` because it requires values for both parameters to work properly.
- Don't assign `COST` values yourself, unless you ***really*** know what you are doing.